# Using DBI fin R for disconnecting a duckdb database and reconnecting gives an error

Tags: r, duckdb

I have the following code setting the database connection to a duckdb file in R. If Iuse disconnect and try to reconnect, I get an error telling me that the file is in use by another process. I have to restart R to be able to reconnect.

```
library("DBI")
con2 <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir="my-db.duckdb", read_only = FALSE)
dbListTables(con2)
dbWriteTable(con2, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbListTables(con2)
dbDisconnect(con2)
con2 <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir="my-db.duckdb", read_only = FALSE)
```

The error message is

```
Error: rapi_startup: Failed to open database: IO Error: Cannot open file "my-db.duckdb": The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process.
```

If I run the lines with a sqlite-file, everything works fine
(e.g. replacing the connection line with

```
con2 <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="myDB.sqlite")
```

Am I missing something?

Cheers

Renger

Comment: Does this happen if you simply connect, disconnect and connect? Also to possibly help you'll need to provide some debugging detail (such as errors)

Comment: as I wrote it happens when I connect, disconnect, reconnect. The error is that the db file is in use by another process. I added the complete error message (translated partly by deepl)

Comment: I get no errors running your example using R 4.2.2, duckdb_0.6.1, DBI_1.1.2 on linux

Comment: I run DBI_1.1.3 on a Windows 10 machine with R 4.0.4 (no possibility to update to R. 4.2). Probably a windows issue?

Comment: Uncertain. The error itself indicates that the connection has not been shut down completely. Perhaps a lingering pointer exists in duckdb_1.1.3, and this is an error to report. Perhaps it can be fixed by forcing the garbage cleaner to run using `gc()` prior to connecting but this seems unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

using

```
dbDisconnect(con2, shutdown = TRUE)
```

resolves the problem.